# Windows 2003 Server shared folder

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, network-share

I'm not really into systems administration, but I was called to set up this Windows 2003 Server. I put it in a VirtualBox virtual machine on the (real) Ubuntu Server. So far, easy stuff.

I'm trying to share a folder of the W2003 machine, so that a program used on the Windows XP (yes, I know) machines can access a file in it.

On every client machine (Windows XP), I'm getting asked the Server's password whenever I try to connect to the shared folder, or even the domain (\\vserver, for example).

On Windows XP, through Control Panel->User Accounts->MyUser->Manage network passwords, I can add the server's password, so I'm never asked again, but I would like to know a way to do this on the server, so I don't have to go through 30 machines (not all of them in this city) enabling this option individually.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Windows XP is still the most widely used desktop OS where a Windows OS is used on the desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server and clients aren't joined to the same Windows AD domain, then you'll need to do this from every workstation.

If the server and clients are joined to the same Windows AD domain, then create an AD group for the users who should have access to this folder, add the users to this group, configure the appropriate Share and NTFS permissions on th shared folder for this group, then log the users off and back on. They'll all then have access to the shared folder.